# Finding cgpoint in array based only on X

Tags: arrays, swift, cgpoint

I have an array of CGPoints in Swift.

I'd like to find a point in the array using only the X value (they all have unique X values, so this shouldn't be a problem) and then get the Y value from that.

I also would like a way to only see if it contains a point with the X value that I'm looking for, like a .contains that only cares about the X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `indexOf:` function to find the index of an item in an array using a predicate. From there, you can access that item with the index.

This actually answers both your questions, because it either returns the index of a `CGPoint` with your X-value, or it returns `nil`.

```
let index = pointArray.indexOf {
    $0.x == xToFind
}

if let index = index {
    let point = pointArray[index]
    // Do something with the point that has the x-value you wanted
} else {
    // There is no point in the array with the x-value you wanted
}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to that over the "iterating through an array and checking each value" approach? I currently found this to work; `var lastY : CGFloat = 0.0
            
            for point in chunksFull {
                if point.x == (roundToChunks(playerSprite.position.x)) {
                    lastY = point.y
                }
            }`

Comment: @niwot0525 Well, using `indexOf:` is more of the Swift way of doing this, because it uses the functional programming that's part of Swift. There are many ways to solve this problem (like with a for loop), but, for me, using `indexOf:` is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

One overly complicated but sweet way to handle problems like this is with Protocols and Extensions.

If we make a `XYType` `protocol` that has a `typealias Element` and `x` and `y` properties of type `Element` we can extend `SequenceType` to encapsulate the `filter` and `contains` methods.

```
protocol XYType {

    typealias Element

    var x : Element { get set }
    var y : Element { get set }

}

extension CGPoint : XYType {}
```

Now the real methods :

Extend `SequenceType` but use constraints. The `Generator.Element` should be an `XYType` and the `Generator.Element.Element` (the `Element` of the `XYType`) should be `Equatable`.

The actual filter function is a bit complicated. But essentially it uses the function it gets as a parameter `includeElement: (Self.Generator.Element.Element) throws -> Bool` and if it is true it appends to a copy. In the end it returns that copy.

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : XYType, Generator.Element.Element : Equatable {

    // this function just mimics the regular filter.
    func filterByX(@noescape includeElement: (Self.Generator.Element.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.Generator.Element] {

        var copy : [Generator.Element] = []

        for element in self where try includeElement(element.x) {

            do {
                let include = try includeElement(element.x)
                if include {
                    copy.append(element)
                }
            } catch {
                continue
            }
        }

        return copy
    }

    func filterByY(@noescape includeElement: (Self.Generator.Element.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.Generator.Element] {

        var copy : [Generator.Element] = []

        for element in self where try includeElement(element.y) {

            do {
                let include = try includeElement(element.y)
                if include {
                    copy.append(element)
                }
            } catch {
                continue
            }
        }

        return copy
    }
}
```

Do the same for `contains`

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : XYType, Generator.Element.Element : Equatable {


    func containsX(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool {

        for element in self {
            do {
                let result = try predicate(element.x)
                if result {
                    return true
                }
            } catch {
                continue
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    func containsY(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool {

        for element in self {
            do {
                let result = try predicate(element.y)
                if result {
                    return true
                }
            } catch {
                continue
            }
        }

        return false
    }

}
```

Tests :

```
let points = [CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1),CGPoint(x: 2, y: 2),CGPoint(x: 3, y: 3),CGPoint(x: 4, y: 4)]

// CGPoint(2,2)
points.filterByY { (y) -> Bool in
    y == 2
}

// false
points.containsX { (x) -> Bool in
    x == 5
}
```

P.S. :

you can also do this, it is a little bit shorter :

```
let filtered = points.filter {
    $0.x == 2
}

let contains = points.contains {
    $0.x == 3
}
```